I want to prevent numbers and special characters in an input, to force a character in the first position
I have already been successful in doing these other things:

prevented first character from being a space using javascript
prevented consecutive spaces using javascript
forced each word in the input to be capitalized using html
Now I want to force the first character to be forced a letter, to prevent a number and special character only in the first character.
I know it can be done but I can not find this helpful code. I have done so much and this is the last thing I need for my form! :D

This is how I did all of the mentioned above:
function SpaceBlock() {
    var space = document.getElementById("real_name");
        if(space.selectionStart === 0 && window.event.code === "Space"){
            window.event.preventDefault(); } }

function SpaceBlock2() {
    var space = document.getElementById("display_name");
        if(space.selectionStart === 0 && window.event.code === "Space"){
            window.event.preventDefault();} }
            
var lastkey;
var ignoreChars = ' \r\n'+String.fromCharCode(0);
function ignoreSpaces(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if(ignoreChars.indexOf(char) >= 0 && ignoreChars.indexOf(lastkey) >= 0) {
        lastkey = char;
        return false; }
    else {
        lastkey = char;
        return true; } }

var lastkey2;
var ignoreChars2 = ' \r\n'+String.fromCharCode(0);
function ignoreSpaces2(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var char2 = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if(ignoreChars2.indexOf(char2) >= 0 && ignoreChars2.indexOf(lastkey2) >= 0) {
        lastkey2 = char2;
        return false; }
    else {
        lastkey2 = char2;
        return true; } }

<input type="text" name="real_name" placeholder="Real Name" id="real_name" required minlength="6" maxlength="24" tabindex="1" onkeydown="SpaceBlock()" onkeypress="return ignoreSpaces(event);" style="text-transform: capitalize;" >

<input type="text" name="display_name" placeholder="Display Name" id="display_name" required minlength="6" maxlength="24" tabindex="1" onkeydown="SpaceBlock()" onkeypress="return ignoreSpaces(event);" style="text-transform: capitalize;" >

This is the last thing I need for my form, just hoping someone will help. Thanks!

Be aware that every effort you invest in input validation on the browser must be invested again on the server. Because users can always manipulate the client, as illustrated here. Perhaps it is simpler to have only the server validate?

I know, I can do all that with php, the trims to get rid of all consecutive spaces and space at beginning and end, and its in the html to capitalize, so this is all there is left, to make sure the first character is a letter which I can figure out in php but I want to prevent number and special characters in the first character and force a letter using javascript

Here's an enhanced and more organized solution that handles below cases:

Preventing the first character from being a space.
Preventing consecutive spaces.
Forcing each word in the input to be capitalized.
Ensuring the first character is a letter, not a number or special character.



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Function to handle all keypress events
    function handleKeyPress(event) {
        const input = event.target;
        const char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

        // Prevent first character from being a space
        if (input.selectionStart === 0 && event.code === "Space") {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // Prevent first character from being a non-letter
        if (input.selectionStart === 0 && !/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // Prevent consecutive spaces
        const lastChar = input.value.charAt(input.selectionStart - 1);
        if (char === " " && lastChar === " ") {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Attach event listeners to input fields
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='real_name'], input[name='display_name']");
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);

        // Set text-transform to capitalize to force capitalization of each word
        input.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
    });
});
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="real_name"
      placeholder="Real Name"
      id="real_name"
      required
      minlength="6"
      maxlength="24"
      tabindex="1"
    />

    <input
      type="text"
      name="display_name"
      placeholder="Display Name"
      id="display_name"
      required
      minlength="6"
      maxlength="24"
      tabindex="2"
    />
    <script src="./temp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy

Thank you! You get the most helpful genius of the day award! Lke wow!! I even understand how to change it and make it work with other inputs. I love it!! Thanks again!!!

I am trying to make a whole 2nd system like that for an email input and treat it different, and it only works for capitalization, it is not working for anything else. I am trying to prevent duplicate . and @ in an email input. Can you help me one more time please? I even tried renaming the function name (x2) and removing the 2nd document.addEventListender("DOMContentLoaded"..... with the extra brackets above to try and make it work with the first.
